# MemberQ and FreeQ not working as expected

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, expression-test

Could someone explain to me why

```
MatchQ[L[1, {3}], L[s_, l___?(FreeQ[#, s_] &)]]
```

returns `False`? I would have expected that since `1` is not in `{3}` the query will be `True` so that the expressions match. Similarly I find

```
MatchQ[L[1, {3}], L[s_, l___?(MemberQ[#, s_] &)]]
```

returns `True` where I would expect it to be `False`.

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps `L[s_,l_]/;FreeQ[l,s]` and `L[s_,l_]/;MemberQ[l,s]` do what you want. See the [documentation for Condition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html).

Comment: Interesting. I myself didn't notice this before reading this question. Not sure if this is already documented or discussed somewhere, but the named pattern inside `PatternTest` isn't _linked_ to the named pattern outside. A clearer example: `aaa /. expr_?(Function[Print[expr_]; True]) :> bbb`, you'll see the printed code is `expr_` rather than `aaa`.

Comment: First I think `___` should be just `_`, or it can match a sequence, even an empty one, and it will evaluate `FreeQ` and `MemberQ` with unexpected arguments. Second, if `s_` is inside `PatternTest` or `Condition` it can't be in the same 'pattern scope' as the first `s_`, that's how these pattern primitives work. So you basically evaluating `FreeQ[{3}, _]` and `MemberQ[{3}, _]`, and it doesn't matter whether the blank `_` has a name or not. If you really want to share a pattern, in this case, I believe `L[s_, {Except[s_] ...}]` works as expected.

Comment: @swish Do you have a reference for the "pattern scope" stuff?

Comment: @xzczd Not really, I put it in quotes as it doesn't really exist, it's just what makes sense to me because I [reimplemented all of the pattern primitives](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/Patterns/) and have some intuition about them now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try tracing it:

```
MatchQ[L[1, {3}], L[s_, l___?(FreeQ[#, s_] &)]] // Trace
```

Result:

```
{MatchQ[L[1,{3}],L[s_,l___?(FreeQ[#1,s_]&)]],
  {(FreeQ[#1,s_]&)[{3}],
   FreeQ[{3},s_],
   False},
 False}
```

So, `FreeQ[#1,s_]&` gets applied to `{3}`, evalutes it's body, and sure enough, the expression `{3}` is not free of `s_` (which is just effectively `_`).

Using `s_` twice in a pattern means that the pattern should match if the same value is found in both positions. But MatchQ wants to evaluate its pattern argument against the target, and its pattern argument in this case involves a PatternTest. It's going to interpret that PatternTest as part of what it needs to evaluate to determine a match, it's not going to interpret it as something to "see" in the target argument.

I obviously don't know what problem you're trying to solve, but this looks very convoluted. You're using MatchQ, which uses patterns, but you're feeding it a pattern whose only meaningful semantic is a predicate. But in turn, that predicate uses FreeQ, which uses patterns. Why not reduce the layers of indirection?

```
FreeQ[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &[L[1, {3}]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: "so it's holding its arguments until it gets applied" Hmm... I don't think the `Hold*` attribute is relevant.  Try `ClearAttributes[Function, HoldAll];
ClearAttributes[PatternTest, HoldRest]; aaa /. expr_?(Function[aaa === expr_]) :> bbb`

Comment: Okay, backing up, the function is either a predicate being used by the pattern, or it's explicitly part of the pattern itself. In other words, OP seems to expect `s_` to be bound to a value when evaluating the function. But `s_` will only be bound to the value that it matches within the expression. There is no FreeQ/Function stuff in the L expression that we're trying to match. The semantics, the way OP wrote it, would be, "match an expression whose first element is also identitcal to a sub-expression that you'll find in a Function deep inside the second element"...

Comment: So, I agree that the hold attribute isn't really relevant. What was in my head was that some function was being evaluated as part of matching `l___`, and there is no reason to expect that the body of that function to be "computed" in real time, so to speak. I'll update my answer.

Comment: As to the "funny story" part, I'm afraid you've misunderstood something… That sample is actually equivalent to `MatchQ[L[1, {3}], L[s_, l___?(FreeQ[#1, ssss] &)]]`. Scoping is not relevant here.

Comment: OMG. Okay, notes to self: (1) don't try to answer SE questions in the moments before you need to leave the house; (2) take some time to figure out how pattern matching f-ing works.

Comment: Sorry, folks, for making a hash out of this question.